# Dell Precision M3800 drivers

Tags: release-freya, drivers

Dell provides a driver manager for installing its drivers on the Dell M3800 running Ubuntu. It's called the Dell Driver Installer and is available through the Ubuntu software centre. Since Freya is based on Ubuntu, I was hoping to install its drivers in this way, but it does not work. The installer simply hangs and nothing happens.

How can I make this installer work or, alternatively, how can I install the drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just searched for your laptop model. The chipset drivers are already installed, so you don't have to worry about that.
You also already have open-source Nvidia drivers, this are not the official drivers but they are free (as in freedom).

If you want to install the official (non free) drivers, you have to open Slingshot and search for 'additional drivers'. Select the driver you want to install, click on apply, wait until the drivers are done installing and reboot.

Comment: Thanx Jeroen. I'll try as soon as I get Ubuntu up and running again.

Comment: @Charl Good luck! The instalation steps are about the same in Ubuntu, but instead of opening Slingshot, you have to search in the dash (the 'start menu' of Ubuntu)